# Styling Different Alert Outcomes?

Tags: css, reactjs, alert, styling

If this is the code for my Alert component:

```
const Alert = ({ message, success }) => (
  <div className={`Alert${success ? ' success' : ''}`}>
    {message}
  </div>
);
```

And I want to style CSS for each outcome – red for an error, green for a successful outcome – if this is the right code to use for that...

```
.Alert {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #ffcccc;
  color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.Alert.success {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: #ccffcc;
  color: green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

...then what am I doing wrong here?

```
  handleAddProperty = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      alertMessage: '',
      isSuccess: false,
      isError: false,
    });
    Axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/PropertyListing', {
      title: this.state.fields.title,
      type: this.state.fields.type,
      bedrooms: this.state.fields.bedrooms,
      bathrooms: this.state.fields.bathrooms,
      price: this.state.fields.price,
      city: this.state.fields.city,
      email: this.state.fields.email,
    })
      .then(() => this.setState({
        isSuccess: true,
        alertMessage: 'Property added successfully.',
      }))
      .catch(() => this.setState({
        isError: true,
        alertMessage: 'Server error. Please try again later.',
      }));
```

Comment: Yes, this should work as expected

Comment: In that case... See my edited version @DacreDenny. Can't quite figure out what I'm missing here...

Comment: can you include the render code showing how the `<Alert/>` is being rendered with your components state?

Comment: Ah of course. Nevermind, I fixed it myself – thanks for giving me a nudge in the right direction, @DacreDenny!

Comment: Hey no worries :-)